# How should I denote static classes in UML?

Tags: c#, uml

So I did some research about how to denote static methods and classes in UML. I found on [these](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=288631) [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) pages that static methods should be denoted by underlining them, but what is the correct way to display a class as being static?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Marking a class as **static** is a very low level information, which we don't put in UML diagrams usually. UML 1.0 as well as 2.0 gives some flexibility to designer/developer to modify the convention if it suits to your audience/team.

You can put a **note** to that class, or use something like `<<static>>`( as used for interface).

Answer (score 8):

I would just use a stereotype `<<static>>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing, but I was wondering whether there was some kind of standardized way of denoting...

Answer (score 2):

The `<<utility>>` stereotype is what you are looking for.

It's defined in UML Standard Profile (as per UML 2.5 documentation) as:

> A class that has no instances, but rather denotes a named collection
> of attributes and operations, all of which are static.

Answer (score 0):

IMO static classes (like in C#) should not even be used in OO Design. A static class cannot be instantiated and thus is actually not a class regarding UML semantics.

You could mark the class as "leaf" (no subclasses) and add a constraint which does not allow non-static members. This would resemble the meaning of the C# static keyword.

Comment: The official documentation confirms, it cannot be instantiated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

Comment: In C# sealed on the other hand means, that another class cannot inherit from the sealed class. This would be equivalent to a "final specification" class in UML.

Answer (score -3):

Static classes are usually denoted by underlining the class name.  Its a convention to underline static features, so it makes sense that underlining the class name would denote a static class.

Comment: Yes but... an underlined name denotes a class instance (as explained in "Learning UML 2.0", page 102)

Comment: Underlining is for static *features* not classes. See chap. 9.4.4 of UML 2.5