# How to show static class in class diagram

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram

I have the following two classes and I would like to create the class diagram. In uml as connect them?

```
public class A {
    public void show(){
        System.out.println(B.C.name());
    }
}
public class B {
    public static class C{
        public static String name(){
            return "class C";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679791/how-should-i-denote-static-classes-in-uml http://www.uml-diagrams.org/nested-classifier.html?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for inner class representation in uml design:

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~sspacey/teaching/COMP204/_/pdf/18.%20Anonymous%20Classes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to show such things is simply to adorn the class with a stereotype. [image]

Comment: the dotted arrow represents a dependency?

Comment: Yes, that's the notation. In this case a dependency is sufficient to tell that A needs (something from) C.